# Set X-frame-options to SAMEORIGIN in angular 6 to block site in iframe tag

Tags: node.js, angular, http-headers, x-frame-options

I want to block my site in the `<iframe>` tag. On research I found that to do so, I need to set the header as 'x-frame-options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Tried setting the meta tag as

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

But this method is outdated since April 2016.

When I am trying to search it is giving me the result for httpClient.
But I want the same when Someone hit my url through .

Do I need to set the header through node or need to do some changes in angular.json

My site is working on node server with URL http://localhost:4200/.

Comment: Did you check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998540/how-to-set-x-frame-options-in-express-js-node-js

Comment: And this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009901/modifying-x-frame-options-on-an-iframe-through-node-js

Comment: Are you using this https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp as web server?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it on angular side, only on server side.

I think you can use this npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-frame-options

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any webserver like Nginx, Apache HTTP Server

example for how to use in Nginx

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
```

in global scope, or location scope.
Better to do in location scope. Because, as soon as you add some header in location scope, the global scope will not reflect

*Additional*

You can take care of more things using the header like cross-site scripting

```
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

Even though nowadays browsers are helping to reduce cross-site scripting. More detail description in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection)